# How to limit a number of firebase storage of images?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I created this piece of code as a rule too limit number of items stored there, but I still can add as many new images, as I want.

```
     match /images/logo/{userId}/{imageId} {
      allow write: if request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
        &&  list(/images/logo/{userId}).size() < 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to limit the number of objects in a Cloud Storage bucket using Firebase security rules.  There is no function `list()` available in security rules.

You're probably better off recording the count of objects in a database and use that in conjunction with a Cloud Functions trigger to determine if an object should be allowed to remain after uploading.

Answer (score 2):

Let the client upload the logo image with the same filename, then there will be only one, even without rules.

Comment: to me a found a good solution, in rules you set the path to be the same as the image ...  match /profiles/{userId}/profile-image rather than using a wide card this will case to override the old one